# How to handle popup messages thrown from web applications in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, popup

I am developing a tool to automate testing of a web application. I want to handle the popup messages thrown in error scenarios. The problem am facing is after a button click a popup message is thrown, but only after a response is given to the message box(ie clicking on any buttons in the message box) the execution continues, till then the web browser is busy waiting for a response. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your application inject some javascript into the page that overrides the default alert/confirm function.  This would allow you to run code before the alert is shown or completely override the functionality so that the alert isn't shown at all.

See this [custom alert demonstration](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) for an easy example of how to override the default alert function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to show the alert message and to handle it according to the application user.